# Setting Grid.ColumnSpan for Button in ItemsSource

Tags: wpf

I have Grid that has some buttons and I need to arrange the order of the button according to the config file.
Below is my Button class where I set the properties of the button.
Is there any way to set the Grid.ColumnsSpan for these buttons?

```
    public class ButtonModel
   {
     public int Index { get; set; }
     public string Content { get; set; }
     public ImageSource Image { get; set; }
     public ICommand Command { get; set; }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

If your Button model has information regarding what should be columnspan for its button.. then you can directly bind the Grid.Column span in xaml to it...

`<Button Grid.ColumnSpan="{Binding ColumnSpan}"/>` assuming buttonmodel has property ColumnSpan..which you initialized from your configuration..